# How to return mismatches as nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract data from various tables based on revision numbers, I only want to see the values that are less than the minimum rev in my primary table, also if the revision number doesn't match or is not available I still want to see a null.

```
T1
Id  t1_Value Rev
1    ABC  123
2    XYZ  234
3    RTY  344
4    MGH  678

T2 
T2Id t1_Id(FK) t2_Value   Rev
1    1        ab12    121
2    1        qw12    122
3    2        rf45    234
4    3        ty67    345


Output:
Id   T1_Value  T2_Value
1    ABC        ab12
1    ABC        qw12
2    XYZ        rf45
3    RTY
4    MGH
```

here is a part of my query:

```
select t1.id, t1.value as t1_value, t2.value as t2_value
from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.t1_id(+)
and nvl(t2.rev,-1)<=t1.rev
```

If I use nvl, it would return #1,2,4. But I am unable to figure our how to return #3, my current query is dropping #3 so I do not see a row for #3 at all. After seeing few responses, I want to add that my data is across multiple tables and I need to do that revision check <=t1.rev for atleast 10 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You would do much better if you used ANSI (SQL Standard) syntax for outer joins.

With the old, deprecated, not recommended proprietary Oracle syntax, which you are using, NVL is not what you need.

Instead, you need the (+) notation after EVERY occurrence of ANYTHING from the second table - not just one time, as in `t2.t1_id(+)`, but also in the second condition:

```
and t2.rev(+) <= t1.rev
```

Comment: but can I outer join the same table multiple times? I have the same revision number check for other tables as well.

Comment: How is this new question related to the one you asked in your original post? Then: Yes, you can outer-join to the same table multiple times; but how you do that depends on your problem. And if the query is more complicated than this, then you should DEFINITELY write outer joins with the SQL Standard syntax (which even Oracle has been recommending for the last 20 years at least!)

Comment: this is not new, like I mentioned in my question, I am extracting data across multiple tables and I have only listed a part of my query in the question. Yes, I have the revision check for all the tables, I have atleast 10 tables for which I need to check <= t1.rev

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.value as t1_value, t2.value as t2_value
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id and t2.rev <= t1.rev;
```

Comment: I tried this, it works but returns the values from t2 although the t2.rev  > t1.rev, in this case how do I return nulls?

Comment: @Skn . . . You may want to use `>=`.  It is hard to tell from your question what filtering you really want.